# How do I send gems to another user in Duolingo?

Tags: duolingo, software

How can I send some gems to my friend in Duolingo?

[Here](https://www.ilovelanguages.com/how-to-send-gems-to-other-duolingo-users/) they say there is a way, but I can't find a "send gems" button in my friend's profile.

Comment: I’m closing this question because it is about a feature of an application that is not directly relevant to language learning. See the meta discussion [Is the "Duolingo gems" question off-topic?](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/q/767/800).